# Drupal: views block override

Tags: drupal

I have a view that gets its content from a taxonomy terms. This view generate around 10 blocks each block is for a certain term. I want to override the output of the block. So is there a proper way to do that? How can I use the preprocess functions to that?

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/node/438370 should help.